# Django Paginator shows post titles Not Page numbers, why?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-pagination

i'm trying to use Django Paginator using ListView, but the paginator shows post title instead of page number:
[Page number replaced with post title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b97Ld.png)

how can i fix that?
this is my code:
in `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.


# PostObject_list by using ListView
class PostList(ListView):
    model=Post
    paginate_by=20
    context_object_name='all_posts'
    ordering=['-created_at']


# allpost by using ListView
'''class AllPost(ListView):
    model=Post
    context_object_name='allpost'
    paginate_by=None
'''    

# Post_singl_object using DetailView
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model=Post
```

in template `post_list.html` :

```
 </div>
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center mt-1">
                    {% if all_posts.has_previous  %}
                    <li class="page-item "><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_posts.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for page in all_posts %}
                        <li class="page-item ">
                        
                             <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}"><span>{{page}}</span></a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                 
                    {% if all_posts.has_next %}
                         <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{all_posts.previous_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Pagination-->
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `all_posts` will not work because this is the object list, not the page object. `all_posts` will not have the page attributes like `paginator`, `has_previous`, `previous_page_number`, etc.

In this case you need to use `page_obj`, which is automatically added by `ListView` to the template context when paginating. You can get the page range from the template using `page_obj.paginator.page_range`:

```
{% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
<li class="page-item ">
   <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}"><span>{{ page }}</span></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The implementation for `Previous` and `Next` will also not work because of the same reason. To resolve that, you also need to use `page_obj`, so all in all:

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous  %}
    <li class="page-item "><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
{% endif %}

{% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    <li class="page-item ">
       <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}"><span>{{ page }}</span></a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: that's wrok, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should access to `paginator`. In your case, `page_obj.paginator`. Try to change your template to:

```
{% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
<li class="page-item ">
   <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}"><span>{{page}}</span></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it works when use paginator function view, but i'm using class based view.. thank you

Comment: my bad, copy-paste issue. I mean `page_obj` instead `all_objects`.  Documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview